# Can submicron mould particles go through building structures, non permeable foil paper?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I read that submicron mould particles and vapours related to mould can go through walls, floors and ceilings?  Is this correct?

Comment: The fact that a room isn't air tight is the problem. There is a light, a wall switch, plumbing, cracks in the flooring, or air conditioning vent that leaks contaminated air into the room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking two different questions

> I read that submicron mould particles can go through walls, floors and
>   ceilings. How so aren't these structures meant to be air tight?

Not true. Mould particles can not seep through concrete walls or thick wood, even though they are porous structures. The interstitial pore size is too small and tortuous to let any mold particle pass through it randomly.

> What about the lowest thickness of foil paper which is meant to be non
>   permeable, can submicron mould particles go through that?

No, an aluminum foil is impervious to solids no matter what their size is. Yes, probably electrons and X-rays will pass through but nothing particulate.